# iOS - push notifications not determined

Tags: ios, push-notification

is there any workaround to find out if user has been ever asked for push notifications permissions?
Calling `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` directly is not sufficient for me. 
I have a screen that changes based on whether it is a first launch of app or not.

1. If it is it says that app can send push notifications and when prompted please tap Allow. Then user click Got it button and and VC with push notifications prompt is displayed.
2. However if user signup up again on another account (push notifications are remembered) I want to display info that he needs to go Settings to allow push notifications (if they are disabled) or just simply skip notifications prompt screen (if user allowed them).

So in other words i need to know not if user has allowed push notification but if he was ever asked for them.

I've tried to save some data in keychain after user was asked but when app is deleted and installed again (after one day or more so push notifications settings are reseted) user is not asked (I only check if there is my flag in keychain).

Thanks for help

Edit #1 I added image that presents my problem[image: Push notifications]

Actually screens with OK and Go to settings buttons are not seperate View Controllers but it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification permission alert is not on per user basis. It'll be prompted only once. You cannot change any settings from your code to get the alert on per user basis.

Even if you delete your app and reinstall it, it won't ask for the permission.

If you really want to have the alert once again you have to follow steps as documented by Apple but certainly not by code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42

Use this if user has denied access

NSUInteger rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

// Set the defaults to disabled unless we find otherwise...

NSString *pushBadge = (rntypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) ? @"enabled" : @"disabled";
    NSString *pushAlert = (rntypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) ? @"enabled" : @"disabled";
NSString *pushSound = (rntypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) ? @"enabled" : @"disabled";

Comment: I understand that. I don't want to force permissions alert to show again. If user during first signup allowed push notifications and then he signs up again then I skip screens that contain informations about push notifications. When user didn't allowed them at first signup I show screen that allows user to skip or to open Settings (Notifications) and change them manually. So I only need to know if there is an entry for my app in notifications settings list.